# Typing randomly (?) stops working in applications, often after they've been open for a while

Tags: keyboard, xubuntu, google-chrome, xfce, gimp

I'm using Xubuntu 18.04.  Sometimes, applications will randomly (?) stop accepting typed input from my keyboard.  This just affects a single application at a time; all other open applications continue to accept keyboard input normally.  Closing and re-launching the application always restores keyboard input.  I've most often observed this happen in applications that are using a fair amount of memory, like Chrome or GIMP, but that's a loose correlation at best; I'm not able to reproduce this reliably by just (for example) opening a ton of tabs in Chrome.  When an application stops accepting keyboard input in this way, nothing except closing and re-launching it will fix it.  I don't see any errors or any other indication that a problem is occurring, apart from not being able to type input into the application.

I'm stumped on this one.  I haven't found any solutions online, or anyone who even seems to be describing the same general problem.  Any ideas on what could be causing this, or ways I could potentially restore keyboard input to an application without closing and re-launching it?

Comment: I have the exact same problem on Ubuntu 20.04.